# html frames - is grabbing a div out of a page possible?

Tags: html, facebook, frames

basically what i want to do is display a facebook photo album on my website.

is there a way to just take a div from a page and put it on yours with like frames?

couldn't think of a better way to do it atm - client isnt exactly computer savy but could handle photo album himself if its through facebook

i guess my backup option is just to have the gallery page link to the facebook albums- but feels kind of cheep to be just to have part of the website just direct users away(but not too bad since the budget was low )

thanks

Comment: Did you come up with anything? Where are you at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no really good way to use frames in the way you're asking and cross domain rules will stop you pulling the content you want with javascript.

I would suggest something a little more developer friendly - like Flickr, there are heaps of API examples out there that will let you pull in info about each image.

From there is your choice of formatting, but making an XML file from the Flickr data and passing it into a jquery / flash gallery is pretty simple.

:)